# Drawing lines on BufferedImage in Java using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, bufferedimage

I have a BufferedImage, which is set to a JLabel, which in turn is part of a JPanel. On the click of a button, I am drawing some lines on the BufferedImage, which is subsequently updated on the panel. Earlier, I was drawing each line one-by-one, which was OK, but was time-inefficient for my purposes. To increase the efficiency, I divided the coordinates of the BufferedImage in 4 parts and drew the lines on each part using threads. Now, after the execution is completed, some random part of the image does not have the lines drawn. Why is that? Is drawing using Graphics2D not thread-safe??

Comment: Question ---> `some random part of the image does not have the lines drawn. Why is that? Is drawing using Graphics2D not thread-safe??`, Answer ---> `for better help sooner post an ` [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

> Is drawing using Graphics2D not thread-safe??

Yes, Swing (and drawing in it) is definitely not thread-safe and rendering errors which you are experiencing are definitely because of that.

Please refer to following tutorial for more details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

As per mKorbel comment, please add SSCCE to receive more specific advice.